# Is there anyway I can shift through the variables so that I can use just 1 "for" loop?

Tags: python

Well, I'm really new to python and basically just messing around and trying to learn how to be more efficient and effective when I code. I made this piece of code to fill a list of grades with the top 150 scoring students. I stopped right at 90% since I didn't need to go lower.

I also wanted everything to be randomized (including the amount of students that got each grade). The reason I wanted to do it with "for" loops was because I needed the students grades to be high rather than just completely random. Think of this as a controlled amount of random. I also reversed each list and sorted it so that the higher grades can have more students. I got the code working but I have no idea how to make it smaller.

Is there any way that I can do what this code does, but less code? Is there anyway I can shift through the variables so that I can use just 1 "for" loop? Instead of assigning 20 variables to the list.

The code should output a list from 1-150 of the highest scoring students.

```
import random

#lists for the three groups 
randomlist = []
testlist = []
testlist2 = []

#Both "for" loops here get 10 numbers. Each of them randomized between 0 ->  (any number of choice)
#These are then put into a list, sorted, reversed to be used to randomize the number of students getting each grade
for i in range(0,10):
        z = random.randint(0, 25)
        testlist.append(z)
testlist.sort(reverse = True)

for i in range(0,10):
        z = random.randint(0, 30)
        testlist2.append(z)
testlist2.sort(reverse = True)

#Each "y" is mapped to one of the numbers in the list
y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9,y10,= testlist

y11,y12,y13,y14,y15,y16,y17,y18,y19,y20 = testlist2

#randomizes an amount of students scoring a grade between 0.5 of each number
for i in range(0,y1):
    n = round(random.uniform(99.5, 100), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y2):
    n = round(random.uniform(99.0, 99.5), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y3):
    n = round(random.uniform(98.5, 99.0), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y4):
    n = round(random.uniform(98.0, 98.5), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y5):
    n = round(random.uniform(97.5, 98.0), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y6):
    n = round(random.uniform(97.0, 97.5), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y7):
    n = round(random.uniform(96.5, 97.0), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y8):
    n = round(random.uniform(96.0, 96.5), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y9):
    n = round(random.uniform(95.5, 96.0), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y10):
    n = round(random.uniform(95.0, 95.5), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y11):
    n = round(random.uniform(94.5, 95.0), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y12):
    n = round(random.uniform(94.0, 94.5), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y13):
    n = round(random.uniform(93.5, 94.0), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y14):
    n = round(random.uniform(93.0, 93.5), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y15):
    n = round(random.uniform(92.5, 93.0), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y16):
    n = round(random.uniform(92.0, 92.5), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y17):
    n = round(random.uniform(91.5, 92.0), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y18):
    n = round(random.uniform(91.0, 91.5), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y19):
    n = round(random.uniform(90.5, 91.0), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)
for i in range(0,y20):
    n = round(random.uniform(90.0, 90.5), 1)
    randomlist.append(n)

randomlist.sort(reverse = True)
print(randomlist[0:150])    #Grabs the first 150 from the sorted reversed list
```

Comment: You need to use lists to hold those values, let’s say you call the list `variables’`and you initialise it to `[]` then you can append values to it and do `for variable in variables:` to iterate over them

Comment: @barny I...cannot believe that I did not realize that. Thank you so much. Seriously haha

Comment: @barny But wait how would I get the random amount of grades between 99.5-100 and 99.0-99.5 ect ect and the same time? Wouldn't the for loops just shift through the list with the same numbers already set?

Comment: @slimeworm, every time you call `random.uniform()`, it returns a new result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code :

```
#lists for the two groups 
randomlist = []
testlist = [] # no need to define two separate test lists

for i in range(0,10):
        z = random.randint(0, 25)
        testlist.append(z)
for i in range(0,10):
        z = random.randint(0, 30)
        testlist.append(z)
testlist.sort(reverse = True)

upper_bound = 100 # your upper bound starts at 100 and decreases by 0.5 after each y variable is dealt with

for y in testlist: # avoids defining all of the y1, y2, y3... variables
    for i in range(0,y):
        n = round(random.uniform(upper_bound - 0.5, upper_bound), 1)
        randomlist.append(n)
    upper_bound -= 0.5

randomlist.sort(reverse = True)
print(randomlist[0:150])    #Grabs the first 150 from the sorted reversed list
```

You could further "compactify" the code that populates `testlist` using list comprehensions :

```
testlist = [random.randint(0, 25) for i in range(0, 10)] + [random.randint(0, 30) for i in range(0, 10)]
testlist.sort(reverse = True)
```

The `+` sign between the two lists **concatenates** them into a single list.

Comment: Wow Ok I fully understood this! Thank you. You minus the 'upper_bound' the second time so that it can continue to decrease right?

Comment: Correct. The line `n = round(random.uniform(upper_bound - 0.5, upper_bound), 1)` does not actually modify the value of upper_bound, but the line `upper_bound -= 0.5` can be translated to `upper_bound = upper_bound - 0.5`, which DOES decrease the value.

Comment: Incredible that the OP's code of almost 100 lines boils down to ten lines …

Comment: Note that `range` starts from zero by default, so all those `range` calls can omit the initial zero: `range(25)` instead of `range(0, 25)`. Also, don't forget to `import random`, and spaces aren't conventionally recommended around the `=` for keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Python offers a syntax called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It allows a shorter syntax for looping trough list and other iterables. Instead of

```py
my_list = []
for i in range(10):
    my_list.append(i)
```

you can just write

```py
my_list = [i for i in range(10)]
```

There are also some built-in functions for working with iterables like [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) that returns a modified (sorted) list you can work with. Instead of

```py
my_list.sort(reverse=True)
print(my_list)
```

it is sometimes better to write

```py
print(sorted(my_list))
```

These ideas inspired me to push list comprehension to its limits by rewriting your code into a one-liner (but for a better representation it's spread over 11 lines).

```py
print(
    sorted([  # sort the resulting list
        round(random.uniform(i/10-0.5, i/10), 1)  # generate the grades,
        for y, i2 in zip(  # zip() turns our to iterable into an iterable of two-tuples
            sorted([random.randint(0, 25)  # generate the 'testlist'
                    for _ in range(10)], reverse=True)  # '_' is used for variables we don't care about
            + sorted([random.randint(0, 30)
                      for _ in range(10)], reverse=True),
            range(1000, 900, -5),  # range() only allows integer steps, so we multiply everything by ten
        ) for i in (i2, ) * y  # second loop takes arguments from first loop
    ], reverse=True)[:150])
```

This code is neither easy to read nor to understand and debugging is a disaster. But I hope it demonstrates how compact code can be written with list comprehension.